# Chart for bicycle component quality?

Tags: brakes, parts, derailleur

I'm not very familiar with all the different component groups available and wondered if there's a chart that ranks their quality (or price).

So I'd know that Shimano 105 is the same level as SRAM Apex (just and example, I don't know).  So I can get it in my head a general idea of where these component sets stack up against each other so when I look at bikes I'll know (generally) the quality of the components.

Surely there's a list somewhere out there, but I can't find it.

Comment: If there isn't a list you should think about compiling one.

Comment: @rothewolf - maybe once I get a better understanding of it.

Comment: Where this gets crazy confusing is when you try to compare groups over time. I have heard that features trickle down the brand's lines over time. So a 2010 Dura-ace might have the same features as a 2013 Ultegra. Which features trickle down and in which year is the real guess from what I can tell.

Comment: Even in the same year, two group levels may be effectively the same. Also, note that for a fixed price, increasing the price of one component means another component must be made a bit cheaper - for example, the Raleigh Sojurn includes a Brooks B17 saddle, but a lot of the drivetrain is lower quality than the competition (but similar tradeoffs can also occur, such as frame weight and what not). So, it doesn't necessarily measure quality.

Comment: Although localized, [this](https://www.sram.com/sites/all/themes/sram_2011/st_rockshox/_images/products/product-matrix.png) can be pretty helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of comparisons in the web, however they tend to get outdated or vanish from time to time, so I won't recommend or link any particular one here. Instead use your favourite search engine with terms like "bicycle/road bike/mountain bike groupset comparison" or the like.

But you can also do a quick check yourself: Choose a component that is usually part of all groups (a derailleur for example), search your favourite online bike shop for it and note the price for the parts from different groups. This should scale fairly well to the whole component group and give you a rough estimate on how they are positioned towards each other.

Comment: this would be my first tack also but it assumes that similar quality parts from different manufacturers are placed at similar prices. I wonder how true this is?

Comment: The main competitors (Shimano and SRAM, not sure about Campa as I'm not that firm on road biking) are serving the mainstream market and don't provide niche applications where one of them could have a substantial advantage through a special feature. Therefore I would assume that their corresponding groups would more or less converge in quality and pricing as none of them provides something that would justify taking way more money for approx. the same quality. As far as I can see, it's mainly a matter of taste or preference than of huge technical difference, which brand is used.

Comment: Thanks.  Can I assume those identifiers not on the list (Shimano 2200, 2300 etc.) are even "lower" than the ones listed?

Comment: @obelia From a quick web search, I would say: yes. Some guy in [this board](http://www.bikeforums.net/showthread.php/395490-Shimano-2200-Brifters) says that sora is something like the 3xxx series. A short look on shimano's website seems to confirm this.

Comment: I'd probably judge Campag and Shimano against each other by price, but I've read good things about sram in terms of value for money. Not surprising maybe since they're the new kids on the block and will want market share. So possibly one might expect slightly better quality from sram for the same price? But this is a hunch rather than a statement - I do run both Shimano and sram but on different types of bikes so can't really compare other than qualitatively (both are good). Incidentally Sora is the line below Tiagra, as you mention above.

Comment: Both of your links are broken

Comment: @ebrohman Thanks for the hint. I have removed them.